# Display the content of a nested map in a particular format

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap

I have used nested map to store the values. I need to print it in particular format.

Input data:

```
University      Department    DeptHead
A                X               Tim
B                X               Jim
C                X               John
A                Y               Alex
C                Z               Peter
D                Z               Dan
B                Z               Ashley
B                Y               Peter
D                Y               Maria
```

Code:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class testNested {

public static void printMap(Map<String, String> map,Object key)
{
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();

   // System.out.print(key.toString());

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
       Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next(); 
       System.out.print(key.toString() + "   "+ pairs.getKey() + "   " +         pairs.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String arg[])
{
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> map= new HashMap<String,Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String,String>A=new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String,String>B=new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String,String>C=new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String,String>D=new HashMap<String, String>();
    A.put("X", "Tim");
    A.put("Y", "Alex");
    B.put("X", "Jim");
    B.put("Z", "Ashley");
    B.put("Y", "Peter");
    C.put("X", "John");
    C.put("Z", "Peter");
    D.put("Y", "Maria");
    D.put("Z", "Dan");
    map.put("A",A);
    map.put("B", B);
    map.put("C", C);
    map.put("D", D);

    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        //System.out.println(pairs.getKey());
        printMap((Map<String, String>)pairs.getValue(),pairs.getKey());
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
D Y   Maria Z   Dan
A Y   Alex X   Tim
B Y   Peter X   Jim Z   Ashley
C X   John Z   Peter
```

I need to display the output in below format (expected output):

```
University      X      Y         Z      
A               Tim    Alex      -  
B               Jim    Peter   Ashley  
C               John   -         Peter  
D               -       Maria     Dan
```

What is the best way to do this using `HashMap`?

What is the best approach for this problem without `HashMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hash map will always print in a random order. If you need to hold an order format of some sort, I would suggest a list of maps, or take it one step further up the abstraction ladder you could just make it a Collection of Maps. That depends on what you need to do with the data. In a distributive setting a HashMap is normally sufficient for this type of data collection, and then a database does the sorting, not the HashMap itself. 

Here is a quick sketch of what I am saying:

```
    private Collection<Map<String, String>> people  = 
                             new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

This way you just make your map and add it into the list in the order that you need. 

If you do make it a collection as suggested you can just pass it around through the constructor like so and do whatever you need to do:

```
    private Set<Map<String, String>> peopleNoDuplicates = 
                            new TreeSet<Map<String, String>>(people);
```

**Added after question was edited:**
I am not able to show everything step by step due to time availability. Sorry, I will come back again and edit if you still have trouble.

You really don't have enough objects in the problem domain to do this properly. You really should have object called "Person" and you should also have an object "University" and a Department object that is a field inside of "University. Then you can use the objects to pass information through each other. otherwise you are missing out on all the great things OOP can do.

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private static instanceCounter = 1000;
//always use the constructor to make sure you get mandatory values in your objects 
public Person(String name){
    setName(name);
    this.id = instanceCounter++;

public final void setName(String name)throws IllegalArg....{
    if(name == null || name.isEmpty()){
        throw new IllegalArg..Ex...("Sorry name is not valid");
    }
    this.name = name;
}

 public String getName.....
```

Then you need a university

```
public class University{
    // in here you can have a some sort of collection or map of dept heads and match them up with a collection of people. ASgain a Map is the fastest way to do this, but this is where you have to put some thought into the problem and think about what is really the best way to do this.
```

You may want to try putting it into a test file using a format object... Idk, it;s your call, but it will require a lot of thought and trial and error. Post back if you get in another jam.

Comment: Collection of map will help me resolve random order format but I am not sure how Collection of map will help as I need to display deptHead for respective University(A,B,C,D) along -ve Y axis and courses(X,Y,Z) along X axis. Can you let me know how can I display data as described above?

Comment: Collection is a pretty abstract term and could be a lot of things. I suggest looking into the Java Collections API to see different ways to use them, focus on a the List and ArrayList, as I think that will help. The rest seems to just be formatting; which I would really try to keep the data and format separate. You can do this by introducing more objects that can handle those aspects. Good luck